# nginx. Test which location used to process request

Tags: debugging, nginx

I'm wondering how do I know if a particular location[s] used to process request in `nginx`.

E.g.:

```
# 1
location / {}

# 2
location ~ /[\w\-]+\.html {}

# 3
location ~ /\w+\.html {}
```

How do I know if URI like `/mysite` is processed by 3rd location and not 2nd?
I tend to use [`add_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) for this matter:

```
location / {
    add_header location 1;
}

location ~ /(\w+\-)\.html {
    add_header location 2;    
}

location @named {
    add_header location named;
}
```

And I'd like to know is there a better solution or what do you personally use for debugging purposes?

Comment: This only adds the header if your HTTP response code is 200, 204, 301, 302 or 304. So it won't help you track 404s : /

Comment: For people coming to this later: in versions of nginx after 1.7.5 (which was released a few months after Air's comment) you can add an `always` parameter to `add_header` which will instruct nginx to always add it, regardless of status code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The add_header trick is how I would do it to.

I'm at work right now, so I can't test but you might possibly get something in the logfile i you set the `error_log` level to:

- `debug`: you're nginx needs to be built using `--with-debug` for this to work, you can check that with the `nginx -V` command
- `notice`: if debug logging isn't enabled

Comment: `add_header` trick doesn't work in precisely those circumstances in which you WANT TO DEBUG most desperately: it doesn't work with 4xx responses.

Comment: You can add_header with always flag. `add_header location 1 always;`

Answer (score 57):

If you just want to see which block was used, and don't care about returning otherwise valid results, it might be more straight-forward to use `return` rather than `add_header`.

```
location / {
    return 200 'location 1';
}

location ~ /(\w+\-)\.html {
    return 200 'location 2';    
}

location @named {
    return 200 'location named';
}
```

Comment: the best answer that i ever saw about testing uris.

Comment: that's really cool way. I had strange problem and almost no location worked. Using this I found it at no time.

Comment: This is quite handy. Add `add_header content-type text/plain;` before the `return` to get it to display in a browser window.

Comment: thanks, this help me a lot

Answer (score 20):

A word of warning on this approach. I found it's a bad idea to use `location` as your debug header, since `Location` is a real header used by the HTTP response 301.

So if (like me) in your testing you end up with this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
Location: http://mydomain.com/banana/
location: banana
```

Then your browser will freak out and report `Duplicate headers received from server`. So use `locationdebug` or something safe.

Comment: banana & lemon is better than foo  & bar! :-)