# nginx reverse proxy in docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm having a trivial problem with nginx. For a starter, I'm just running nginx and portainer as containers. Portainer is running on port 9000 and the containers are on the same docker network so it's not a visibilty issue. Nginx exposes port 80 and works fine. So does portainer when accessing 9000 directly. I'm mapping the nginx volumes /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro and /usr/share/nginx/html:ro locally and they react to changes so I should be hooked up correctly. In my mapped nginx.conf (http section) I have

```
server {
    location /portainer {
        proxy_pass http://portainer:9000;
     }
}
```

where portainer is named, well, portainer. I've also tried with an upstream-directive+server but that didn't work either.

When accessing localhost/portainer logs nginx shows

2018/04/30 09:21:32 [error] 7#7: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/portainer" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /portainer HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

which would indicate that the location directive is not even hit(?). I've tried / in various places but to no avail. I'm guessing it's something trivial I'm missing.

Thanks in advance,
  Nik

Answer (score 2):

I had to add a trailing slash to both lines:

```
server {
    location /portainer/ {
        proxy_pass http://portainer:9000/;
     }
}
```

Comment: I've tried all combinations but now I'm starting to think that there is a more generic setup issue since I'm running my Ubuntu inside a VirtualBox with NAT and port forwarding and the docker containers inside the Ubuntu. I'll have to see how it reacts when run on a "true" virtual machine on another host...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
location ~* ^/portainer/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass http://portainer:9000/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Ref: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html

Comment: Unfortunately that produces the same 404. Really strange, I've seen dozens of examples and in most cases proxy_pass http://container_name:port or http://container with a upstream server container server container_name:port appear to work...

Comment: In that case you might want to debug if the first-matching location is defined elsewhere. I’m not sure if Nginx provides a direct means of finding that, maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/12703702 can help.

Comment: It's a fresh nginx install so I'd be very surprised if there would be another matching location. Especially since it appears like it would hit *no* location (the portainer just gets added to my static contents root)