# Unable to load staticfiles after deploying django app on aws-ec2

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, django-deployment

I am a beginner in aws and I am trying to deploy a django app on `aws-ec2`. I have set-up `gunicorn` application server and `nginx` web server and app loads but without static files. I have followed many answers on stackoverflow but I am unable to fix my problem.

I tried with both `root` and `alias` but they didn't work. The project structure is as follows:-
`/home/ubuntu/myskillhut/`

django.conf(nginx configuration file)

```
server {
        ...

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myskillhut/app.sock;
        }

        location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
                alias /home/ubuntu/myskillhut/static/;
        }
}
```

settings.py

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"), )
...
```

Comment: What would the static files be? image/font/js/css/html ?

Comment: @RandyLam CSS, JS and images

Answer (score 0):

Configuration below works for my project

```
location ~* \.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ {
    root /home/ubuntu/myskillhut/static/;
    expires 1M;
}

location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
    root /home/ubuntu/myskillhut/static/;
    expires 1d;
}
```

Also, make sure nginx can access those files in that dir (../static/)

Comment: Just pick up a skill to see which location the request ends up in. more detail ref to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703702/nginx-test-which-location-used-to-process-request/40297052#40297052